# creating a modal with a button, React, Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

this is my first question on here :) I'm relatively new to React and have a simple question. I'm just trying to add a new function that creates a Modal, then call it onClick when you press the add icon (line 43). Thanks! P.S. I already tried a couple different ways and I keep getting white screens :P

```js
export default class Dayview extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
  
      this.employees = ['Qwynn'];
      this.hourparams = [9,19];
      this.weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
      this.months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
      'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  
      this.state = {
        currentDay: new Date()
      }
    }
  
    changeCurrentDay = (day) => {
      this.setState({ currentDay: new Date(day.year, day.month, day.number) });
    }
  
    nextMonth = () => {
      this.setState({ currentDay: new Date(this.state.currentDay.setDate(this.state.currentDay.getDate() + 28)) });
    }
  
    previousMonth = () => {
      this.setState({ currentDay: new Date(this.state.currentDay.setDate(this.state.currentDay.getDate() - 28)) });
    }

    addAppt = () => {
      
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <div className="dayview-header">
            <div className="title">
            <h2>{this.months[this.state.currentDay.getMonth()]} {this.state.currentDay.getFullYear()}</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="tools">
          <button onClick={this.previousMonth}>
              <AddBoxIcon className="material-icons"/>
            </button>
            <button onClick={this.previousMonth}>
              <ArrowBackIcon className="material-icons"/>
            </button>
            <p>{this.months[this.state.currentDay.getMonth()].substring(0, 3)} {this.state.currentDay.getDate()}</p>
            <button onClick={this.nextMonth}>
              <ArrowForwardIcon className="material-icons"/>
            </button>
          </div>
            </div>
            <DayviewHours />
        </div>
        
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using class component, first you need to declare/initialize an `open` object inside your `this.state` constructor to control whether the `modal` is open or close. Its default should be `false`,

```
this.state = {
  currentDay: new Date(),
  open: false
};
```

In the Modal component, you could pass in the `open` state as a prop to control the modal,

```
<Modal
    open={this.state.open}
    onClose={this.handleClose}
>
```

Here is your button,

```
<button onClick={this.handleOpen}>
     <AddBoxIcon className="material-icons" />
</button>
```

To open the modal,

```
handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
};
```

To close the modal you could use the `onClose` prop given by the MUI doc,

> Callback fired when the component requests to be closed. The reason parameter can optionally be used to control the response to onClose

```
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
```

Full code here in codesandbox: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-matsumoto-svnn21?file=/src/Dayview.js:1018-1091)